# Getting a textblock to display user input while saving previous input

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to get a textblock to act as a display of user input.
txtDisplay is the textblock where data will be displayed.
txtInput is a textbox where data will be input.

```
    public void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Return)
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtInput.Text;
            txtInput.Text = "";

        }           
    }
```

This bit of code works to capture the user input from the input box, display it in the display box and clear out the input box to ready it for a new command. However, once I put new information in the input box and press enter it simply overwrites what is in the display box.

Maybe I'm just not searching the right keywords, but I can't seem to find any help on the topic. If anyone has any suggestions or references it would be appreciated.

Comment: is there any binding applied? secondly the code is more like win forms style, you may perhaps leverage WPF's capabilities.

Comment: No, there isn't any data binding. I'm just reading the MSDN page on that now and I think I can figure something out based on that. Thank you for the insight, I'll see what I can come up with to take better advantage of the WPF.

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving state of the last enter, append the text instead:

```
txtDisplay.Text += txtInput.Text;
```

Note you may need to strip out the `\r\n` since that is not needed such as

```
txtDisplay.Text += Regex.Replace(txtInput.Text, @"([\r\n]+)", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find it far easier to bind the contents of the text display to the text box.

```
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=InputTextBox, Path=Text}" />
```